# Continuous functions such that $f(x)+f(x^2)=x$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-equations

> Find all continuous $f :[0,1]\to \mathbb R$ such that $\forall x\in [0,1], f(x)+f(x^2)=x$

I suspect there are none.

I made little progress so far, but it's worth noticing that $f(0)=0$ and $\displaystyle f(x)+\lim_{n\to\infty}\left((-1)^n\sum_0^{n-1}(-1)^{k+1}x^{2^k}\right)=0$

Comment: $f(0)=0$ is fine but i do not understand the other equation...

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik there may be a mistake, but I just iterated the identity on $f(x^{2^n})$ and took the limit at $n \to \infty$